# How to install QtQuick 1.1 on QT 5.1.1

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick, qtquick2

I developed a project on **Windows** using **Qt 5.1.1** and used the **QtQuick 2.0** import in the QML files. Lately I discovered that my application requires **OpenGL 2.0** or greater, hence it can't run on systems that have OpenGL 1.0. I searched and found that this happens because of the QtQuick 2.0 import.

The **problem** is:
I cannot just modify the import from QtQuick 2.0 to QtQuick 1.0 because I get errors:

```
QtQuick 1.0  module verison is not installed
```

**So how can I install only QtQuick 1.0?** I also Installed Qt 4.7 that comes with QtQuick 4.7 but it happens to be quite hard work to port from Qt 5.1.1 to Qt 4.7. It's not that simple, so I want to keep it as simple as possible and install QtQuick 1.0 on Qt 5.1.1.

Note: I am not doing strange things in the QML files; the QML code should work with no problems with QtQuick 1.0.

Comment: Are we supposed to know what SF means?

Comment: SF- Science Fiction. Sorry for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt Quick 1 is using a different QML engine. You can't use it from within the contemporary QML engine. You need to use the [Qt Declarative](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtquick.html) module (see [list of modules](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtmodules.html)), which provides a Qt 4.8-style Qt Quick 1 implementation. This module is usually installed by default.

Comment: This is a good hint. Meanwhile I found an opengl dll that works fine on systems that have only OpenGL 1.0 installed, so  my application works perfectly on older windows systems. But, I will consider this as an answer and in my spare time I will definitely try Qt Declarative module. Thank you Kuba! :)